# Can I copy Android code into my project?

Tags: android

There is a class in the Android source that makes a variable private that I wish to make public or at least provide a getter method.  Does it go against the Apache license if I copy this file to my project and create a getter method?  Fyi, this is for a commercial app so I don't want to do anything against the standard procedure.

Thanks!

Comment: IMO, It's ok to copy to your commercial app.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve with all this. What is gonna happen if the variable value is vary in different Android versions ? Your application gonna brake ?

Comment: The class in question is SwipeRefreshLayout.  I'm trying to detect the amount that has been pulled down.  There is a variable that holds the percentage of drag, but it is private.  It should be the same on all devices since it is a percentage.  You can see my original question on my profile page.